# What is the smallest convex set includes all smooth unit curves?

Tags: geometry

I try to understand: is there a smallest in area convex set that every smooth curve with length 1 can be placed inside it by translation and rotation?

I only have a upper bound $S \leq \frac14+\frac{\pi}{16}$ because of convex hull of two circles radius $\frac14$ and simple lower bound $S\geq\frac1{4\pi}$.

Does this set exist and what is its length?

Comment: Is your question the same as this one on MathOverflow? [Smallest area shape that covers all unit length curve](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/32477/smallest-area-shape-that-covers-all-unit-length-curve)

Comment: Oh, I've searched here, not on the MathOverflow because this problem looks so pretty simple. Thx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is entry D18, "The worm problem," in the book *Unsolved Problems in Geometry* (Croft, Falconer, and Guy, 1991):

> Leo Moser asked what are the minimal comfortable living quarters for a "unit worm"?

They credit the smallest cover yet discovered to Gerriets & Poole (in 1973 or 1974), and describe it as a "certain truncated rhombus of area less than $0.286$...".  Maybe someone will have a link or reference to the particular shape?  For your bounds, I would only point out that the convex hull of a semicircle of arclength $1$, with radius $1/\pi$ and area $1/(2\pi)$, gives a better lower bound (of $0.159...$).

Comment: https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.bams/1183534466